# No need for spin?

Tags: quantum-spin

Here's a cool idea: we don't need spin: recall that a quantum field arises from an attempt to construct an object that transforms unitarily under $SO(1,3)$ (i.e. by choosing a representation).

A scalar field $\varphi$ will do. No need for spinors and polarization crap. To see this, let $T,R,\Lambda$ denote a translation, a rotation, and a boost respectively. Then:
$$\langle T\varphi(x),T\psi(x)\rangle=\langle\varphi(x+a),\psi(x+a)\rangle=\langle\varphi(x),\psi(x)\rangle$$  Similarly, we can verify that inner products, and thus the laws of physics, are invariant under rotations $(R)$ and boosts $(\Lambda)$ as well. So we might as well call all particles "spin 0" for the sake of simplicity.

---

If you now argue that spin is a physical and measurable attribute like position, I can say this: why then construct representations of $SO(1,3)$ for spin? Spin isn't a 4-vector: it's a 3-vector. So we don't even know how it transforms under, say, a boost.

Moreover, Lorentz transforms are only defined in terms of actions on space-time. We can't just extrapolate that we can apply Lorentz transformations to something completely different, can we? Does this imply that spin has a "time" component? What would that even mean?

- One last thing: spin is, physically, an electromagnetic interaction, right? So there is no way to measure spin without referring to electromagnetism?

Comment: In retrospect, this means that the definition of spin as a choice of representation of $SO(1,3)$ and the definition as an electromagnetic coupling property clash. I wonder how that resolves itself.

Comment: can Fermi-Dirac and Bose-Einstein statistics come out of such a theoretical manipulation? How about the  Pauli exclusion principle? Seems to me you are playing mathematical games and are forgetting experimental observations, which last are the only reason theoretical physics exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lorentz group isn't unitary, so fields don't transform unitarily under $SO(3, 1)$ (there is the reason why the Lorentz group can't represent particles). The "real" quantum field arises from an attemption to build Poincare group representations. Poincare group has two Casimir operators, one of it has the invariant value the square of the spin - $-m^{2}s(s + 1)$ for a given representation, where $s$ refers to the spin number (about it is written below). Corresponding (to this Casimir operator) covariant object (4-vector) which haracterizes the spin is called Pauli-Lubanski vector.  Alternatively, there is spin 4-tensor which has a structure which is analoguously to orbital momentum tensor. So, there is, of course, relativistic description. The similar question "Why we use magnetic field $\mathbf B$ and electric field $\mathbf E$ for the description of EM field? There are not 4-vectors" has the same answer.

As for exactly spin number - you're right: formally it arises when we construct the fields as the irreducible representation of the Lorentz group. But the spin number, of course, is invariant under transformations of the Lorentz group, because it refers to the sum of orders of two $SU(2)$ representations and so it is ordinary number.

"...Similarly, we can verify that inner products, and thus the laws of physics, are invariant under rotations..."
The physical laws aren't invariant under rotations, and one of the reasoning is the spin. We need spin because we observe it. As for example of affecting of spin to observed non-invariance under rotations, the square of amplitude for some process $|1, 2 ,...\rangle \to |1',2',... \rangle$ becomes invariant only after summation on polarizations of all particles. We can observe this fact by experiment.

"...One last thing: spin is, physically, an electromagnetic interaction, right? So there is no way to measure spin without referring to electromagnetism?.."

The measure of EM interaction is electric charge, which refers to internal symmetry of a given theory. An internal symmetry isn't descripted by Poincare (or Lorentz, of course) symmetry. There are some attemptions to unify them (by expanding Poincare group algebra), but the "bare" Poincare group (and Lorentz one) representation doesn't contain information about charge.

You can measure the spin in each cases when it affect on interaction. Basically the most strong observed effects are EM effects (in our scale of energies and distanses), so there is nothing strange that many oservations are making by using EM interaction.

So the physical sense of spin is only that it is a proper angular momentum.

Comment: I think there is a spin-0, unitary representation representation of the Poincare group. Why aren't all particles spin 0?

Comment: I do not understand a point in your answer. Physics IS invariant under rotations of SO(3). Maybe you are saying that the relevant group is SU(2), but it is disputable in view of the spin superselection rule...Moreover, yes SO(3,1) is not unitary, but fields do transform under a unitary rep of that group, just because it is a subgroup of Poincare' group whose particles are irreducible unitary representations. Finally, yes the spin is a 3 vector, a spacelike vector in the rest reference frame of the particle. Changing frame it gets a temporal component, obviously.

Comment: "...Physics IS invariant under rotations of SO(3)..."
I've meaned that physical processes depend on polarizations.

"...fields do transform under a unitary rep of that group,..."
The matrix of fields Lorentz (!) transformation can't be unitary, because boosts generators are antihermitean while rotations generators are hermitean. The simple example is Lorentz transformations of the Dirac spinor.

Comment: "...Finally, yes the spin is a 3 vector, a spacelike vector in the rest reference frame of the particle..."
Corresponding part of the answer is connected with the asker's statement that spin is 3-vector, so we don't know how it is transformed.

Comment: I am not sure I have understood your point. When one says that physics is invariant under rotations he/she means that the observables of the system and/or the dynamics are invariant under the relevant **representation** of the group of the rotations, which is unitary if we are dealing with QM, canonical if we are dealing with Hamiltonian mechanics, and so on. In this sense classical, relativistic and quantum physics is invariant under rotations (if working in an inertial reference frame). I do not understand if you agree with me on this.

Comment: Regarding boosts, in the *Hilbert space* of the theory, of a quantum particle, there is a *unitary* representation $U_\Lambda$ of of $SO(3,1)$ and thus also of each one-parameter group of the boost transformations. Spinor fields operators transform under that unitary rep. $\Psi(x)\to U_\Lambda \Psi(x) U_\lambda^\dagger = S_\Lambda \Psi(\Lambda x)$. It seems that I am referring to $U_\Lambda$ (unitary) while you are referring to $S_\Lambda$ (non unitary).